# How to show custom frame for every page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, geometry, tikzpagenodes

I want to get an easy way to see the frames for main text, margins, and header and footer. It is easy to achieve this using `showframe` option in `geometry` package. However, this option shows the frame in black color and does not allow for the option to determine what exactly to show.

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    \geometry{twoside=false, showframe=false}
    
    % Horizontal
    \geometry{inner=11mm, outer=11mm, includemp=true, bindingoffset=0mm, marginparsep=2.5mm, marginparwidth=25mm}
    
    % Vertical
    \geometry{top=11mm, bottom=11mm, includehead=false, includefoot=false, headheight=3.75mm, headsep=1mm, footskip=\dimexpr 3.75mm + 1mm \relax}

% END_FOLD

\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    % Main text
    \newcommand{\pageframeMainText}{%c
        \tikz[remember picture,overlay] {
            
            \draw [gray, line width=0.1mm, opacity=0.1]
            (current page text area.south west)
            rectangle
            (current page text area.north east);
            
        }
    }
    
    % Margins
    \newcommand{\pageframeMargins}{%
        \tikz[remember picture,overlay] {
            
            \draw [gray, line width=0.1mm, opacity=0.1]
            (current page marginpar area.south west)
            rectangle
            (current page marginpar area.north east);
            
        }
    }
    
    % Header and footer
    \newcommand{\pageframeHeaderFooter}{%
        \tikz[remember picture,overlay] {
            
            % Header
            \draw [DodgerBlue3, line width=0.1mm, opacity=0.1]
            (current page header area.south west)
            rectangle
            (current page header area.north east);
            
            % Footer
            \draw [DodgerBlue3, line width=0.1mm, opacity=0.1]
            (current page footer area.south west)
            rectangle
            (current page footer area.north east);
            
        }
    }

\usepackage{bophook}
\usepackage{ifdraft}
    
    \ifoptiondraft%
        {\AtBeginPage{\pageframeMainText\pageframeMargins\pageframeHeaderFooter}}%
        {}

% END_FOLD

\begin{document}
    
    \noindent%
    \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

The result is as desired. However, Good frame should blend with the background to minimize distractions while also be able to see the frame for fine-tuning. I think it is better to augment the original code to achieve the following requirements

1. It should be possible to determine the `color`, `line width`, and
   `opacity` of all frames
2. It should be possible to enable some frames and disable others

Comment: I believe that `showframe` is not meant to create an undesirable frame on the pages. - it is meant for testing purposes. It does not make sense to have that customisable.

Answer (score 1):

For changing the colour of the frame, you can use this method:

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}

\usepackage[]{xcolor}

\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\let\org@Gm@pageframes\Gm@pageframes
\renewcommand*{\Gm@pageframes}{%
  \begingroup
    \color{red!50}%
    \org@Gm@pageframes
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    
    \noindent%
    \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
    
\end{document}
```

(for everything which needs more fine control than that, I suggest to use your tikz code instead)